# GNU m4: escaping backticks (`)

Tags: escaping, backticks, m4

A simple GNU m4 question, but I cannot find the correct answer. I'd like to print a markdown header starting/ending a code section:

````
```
echo Hello
```
````

How do I create a GNU M4 macro containing the 3 backticks ? something like

`````
define(`md_code',````')
md_code
echo Hello
md_code
`````

Answer (score 11, accepted):

got an answer from Eric Blake on the M4 mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/m4-discuss/2015-04/msg00004.html

> changequote is your friend.  This will do it:

````
define(`md_code', changequote([, 
])[changequote([,])```changequote(`,')]changequote(`,'))
````

> I have to change quotes twice: once around the macro definition, since
>   the definition itself intends to use (backticks) in an unbalanced manner; and
>   again in the macro expansion, since the expansion will output backticks in an
>   unbalanced manner; for each changed quote, the original quotes must be
>   restored.  This assumes that the default quoting stays at (backticks) '
>   throughout the m4 run.
>
> Although in your case, I'd recommend using changequote up front to
>   something else, and globally write your input under those quoting
>   rules instead of the default (backticks) ' quoting rules.  Remember that
>   autoconf intentionally went with [ ] as the quoting characters,
>   because they were much likely to be balanced in output, as opposed to
>   (backticks) and ' not occurring in balanced pairs in shell scripts.  In fact,
>   choosing 2- or 3-byte quoting strings is even less ambiguous, although
>   it then requires more typing.